# facade.edit does not change the database

Tags: facade

I am working on a JSF project that deals with MySQL DB. 
in my backbean method I did:

```
entityFacade.edit(entity object);
```

after that I wanted to make sure of the changes, I queried my database to retrieve the edited record, However, the retrieved values are the old ones. it is like entityFacade.edit(entity object); was not made.

I solved this problem by doing this

```
entityFacade.remove(entity object);
entityFacade.create(entity object);
```

But the problem is that the object has ID which is auto-increment & I want to keep the old ID.

I don't get why the edit does not change values. what are the possible causes of this problem?
Looking forward to your answers, experts.

Comment: All the tags are wrong... Most likely entityFacade is **your** code, so **you** are the only one who can fix it

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 
Im not sure what do you mean by "tags". Also, I used the entityFacade.edit() in other backbeans in the project and they worked..

Comment: Look at my edit and see what 'tags' I removed. 'facade'  is the only one left now

Comment: OK you're talking about the question tags.. Btw entityFacade code is not written by me, I added them from "session beans for entity classes". Also, I used the same entityFacade.edit() in other back beans in the project and they was working fine.

Comment: Even if you copied the code  from somewhere else, it is your code and not part of a framework or the jdk and we can never know what it does.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are facing the same problem, I solved it as follows:
The problem was **not** with the facade.edit() 
it was with the queries.
Try facade.find(id) to retrieve the records from the database instead of queries. The retrieved records will show the edited data.